# Is there a data serialisation language (or program/editor) without repeating property names?

Tags: python, json, serialization, yaml

So I'm working on a program (one for my own amusement, as often is the case). Still nowhere near as good as I'd like to be ***snip long story*** anyways I'm trying for my first time to use an external configuration file rather than have variables littered throughout the source (Python, so not hard to change, just need your good friend Ctrl+F).

Been looking at JSON mostly, but for objects which have more than one value (so I can't just use a key: value pair) I need to write the field names for each entry, which gets annoying. Some demo data (i.e. not a configuration file):

```json
{
  "people": [
    {"first": "John", "second": "Smith", "age": 34},
    {"first": "Jane", "second": "Doe", "age": 40},
    {"first": "Fred", "second": "Blogs", "age": 56}
    ]
}
```

Gets really annoying as I add more people. I know it's for readability, but it adds to my workload.

Also looked at YAML, but still the same basic problem:

```yaml
---
people:
- first: John
  second: Smith
  age: 34
- first: Jane
  second: Doe
  age: 40
- first: Fred
  second: Blogs
  age: 56
```

The easiest solution I can think of is just to have the values in an array without names and assign them in the program by iterating through the array, but that defeats the purpose of readability. (n.b. just code just written off the top of my head so hopefully it's the right code)

*people.json:*

```json
{
  "people": [
    ["John", "Smith", 34],
    ["Jane", "Doe", 40],
    ["Fred", "Blogs", 56]
    ]
}
```

*peoples.py:*

```python
import json

class person:
    def __init__(self, first, second, age):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
        self.age = age

people_file = open("people.json", "r")
people_data = json.load(people_file)

all_people = list()
for each_person in people_data["people"]:
    new_person = person(each_person[0], each_person[1], each_person[2])
    all_people.append(new_person)
```

I think how GFM does tables would work great, but I'm not aware of any languages which support it (I know this could be prettier if I lined it up).

```markdown
|first|second|age|
|-----|------|---|
|John|Smith|34|
|Jane|Doe|40|
|Fred|Blogs|56|
```

Umm... I hope people can make a question out of all that. Is there something I'm missing, a language (or maybe an editor or something) where I don't need to repeat myself so much? I know "easy" would probably by a CSV file (although I might run afoul of having to escape several special characters, as I said 3 miles above in my opening paragraph, this is a config file, but people are an easier example), but that defeats the purpose of having all my settings in one place.

Answer (score 0):

YAML, unlike JSON, has comments, so this would work:

```yaml
people:
  #   first, second, age
  - [ John , Smith , 34 ]
  - [ Jane , Doe   , 40 ]
  - [ Fred , Blogs , 56 ]
```

Comment: I was about to ask what should I do if some people only have certain fields (because to turn that into a list of people I need to iterate each item by index, not field name) but then I looked up the spec and saw that a null is as easy as ~ in YAML so I'm assuming this would work:
```lang-yaml
people:
  #   first, second, age, job,     wage
  - [ John , Smith , 34,  plumber, 2000]
  - [ Jane , Doe   , 40,  ~,       10000]
  - [ Fred , Blogs , 56,  professional idiot ]
```
Ack, just realised SO doesn't let you do code blocks in comments. Just use your imagination to add proper whitespace

Comment: This is obviously a workaround because no text-based data serialization format I know of implements actual ASCII-art tables. Those exist only in markup languages where you want to *render* tables, like Markdown, AsciiDoc, or rST. However when you're in control of the loading code, you can use whatever format to deal with omitting cell values. For example, instead of `~` you could more explicitly write `!!null` or even implement your own local tag `!omit` (needs custom constructor in PyYAML). Not writing anything between commas also works.

Comment: Given my main problem was to avoid tediously typing out the name for each field every time, could I just do something like this? Edit: god damn collapsing line breaks in comments: putting a \ at the end of each row (just for this comment) so you can easily replace that with newlines if you can't visualise my evil schemes.
---\
people:\
  -  - John\
     - Smith\
     - 34\
  -  - Jane\
     - Doe\
     - 40

Comment: My crystal ball thinks you want to write the code shown above, but with block instead of flow syntax. That's possible, though it doesn't let you label the columns, which was the initially stated problem (see your JSON example).

Comment: My crystal ball (I'm assuming it is one, it's too foggy for me to see anything) just wants to have people in a configuration file which can easily be read (by people) without the hassle of repeating myself so often. Maybe I should just embed some CSV in one of my settings ;)

Comment: Then you can do either what I proposed or what you proposed in your comment, whatever fits better. My approach lets you label the columns for better readability; whether you need that or not is your call. From the YAML point of view, both approaches have identical semantics.